# how can delete/remove values from list/set/dict in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I created a list, a set and a dict and now I want to remove certain items from them

```
N = [10**i for i in range(0,3)] #range(3,7) for 1000 to 1M
    for i in N:
        con_list = []
        con_set = set()
        con_dict = {}
        for x in range (i): #this is the list
            con_list.append(x)
            print(con_list)
        for x in range(i): #this is the set
            con_set.add(x)
            print(con_set)
        for x in range(i): #this is the dict
            con_dict = dict(zip(range(x), range(x)))
            print(con_dict)
```

items to remove

```
n = min(10000, int(0.1 * len(con_list)))
indeces_to_delete = sorted(random.sample(range(i),n), reverse=True)
```

now if I add this:

```
for a in indeces_to_delete:
     del con_list[a]
     print(con_list)
```

it doesn't work

Need to do the same for a set and a dict

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is: when you delete a certain item a, the list has changed already. So maybe the for loop is the problem... EDIT: stop, I have not recognised your `sorted`

Comment: why are you doing all this? what is the end goal? what error are you getting?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please elaborate on what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an item from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-item-from-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Sosel How is this a duplicate of that? He's already using `del`, and he's not actually deleting anything from a dict in his sample code.

Comment: @glibdud He asked for removing in sets, lists and dicts (see title)

Comment: @Sosel Sure, but he's already doing what your "dupe" suggests. He needs to provide more info to narrow down what his problem actually is, but it's definitely not learning about `del`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop`
On a dict:

```
d = {'a': 'test', 'b': 'test2'}
```

calling `d.pop('b')` will remove the key/value pair for key `b`

on list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

calling `l.pop(2)` will remove the third element (as list index start at 0)

Beware on set:

```
s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

calling `s.pop()` will remove a random element as discussed here: [In python, is set.pop() deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432022/in-python-is-set-pop-deterministic)

you should use `s.discard('a')` to remove element `'a'`

More infos here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html