# Is there a Python dict without values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Instead of this:

```
a = {"foo": None, "bar": None}
```

Is there a way to write this?

```
b = {"foo", "bar"}
```

And still let `b` have constant time access (i.e. not a Python set, which cannot be keyed into)?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot be keyed into"?  If there are no values, the only way to "key in" is to see if a key is present, which sets can do with `obj in set`.

Comment: Does `obj in set` have constant time access?

Comment: its unclear what you are asking for... specifically what kind of access you need to it, and what you mean by keyed-into

Comment: @RohitJain actually the worst case is O(n) iirc

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: Sure, but that's the same as for `dict`.

Comment: @JohnY well I never said otherwise :-)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity  ... yeah but avg case of O(1)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Right.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: Then your response should be to OP, who stated that he wants "the same constant-time access that dicts have". Well, dicts don't technically have constant-time access. In any case, sets behave identically to dicts when it comes to checking whether a key is present.

Comment: python3 dict `keys` support set operations

Comment: @JohnY: one could say that sets have the same constant-time access that dicts have in that both don't have it =P.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually, in Python 2.7 and 3.2+, this really does work:

```
>>> b = {"foo", "bar"}
>>> b
set(['foo', 'bar'])
```

You can't use `[]` access on a set ("key into"), but you can test for inclusion:

```
>>> 'x' in b
False
>>> 'foo' in b
True
```

Sets are as close to value-less dictionaries as it gets. They have average-case constant-time access, require hashable objects (i.e. no storing lists or dicts in sets), and even support their own comprehension syntax:

```
{x**2 for x in xrange(100)}
```

Comment: how do you add a valueless key though like b += ... ?

Comment: Use `b.add(v)` for single items or `b.update(v)` to copy elements from an iterable.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, `sets`:

```
set() -> new empty set object
set(iterable) -> new set object

Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
```

Related: [How is set() implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-cpythons-set-implemented)

Time complexity : https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set

Comment: Note `set` literals only in 2.7 or 3.x

Answer (score 4):

In order to "key" into a set in constant time use `in`:

```
>>> s = set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
>>> 'foo' in s
True
>>> 'fork' in s
False
```

Comment: This might slightly confusing. `"a"` is in the set because `set("abcd")` treated the string as an iterable of four characters. `set("abcd")` is the same as `set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])`.
So while `"fork"` definitely isn't in the set, neither is `"abcd"`, which this answer could imply.

Comment: `set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz')` should be `set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`, this is clearer though :)