# Set is much faster than list while lookup for membership

Tags: python, list, set

How set is much much faster in lookup for an element than list, is that something to do with the ordered maintain in list ? or is the lookup algorithm is different in set than list ?

```
>>> from timeit import Timer    
>>> Timer("100042 in L", "L=range(100000)").timeit(number=10000)
21.69940710067749
>>>
>>> Timer("100042 in S", "S=set(range(100000))").timeit(number=10000)
0.0006740093231201172
>>>
```

Some one pleae point me out any link or algorithm used between the two ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set` uses hashing ([it allows only items which are hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)), which will be much faster than `list`'s sequential access, for random lookup.

But, `list` might beat `set`, if the item being searched is at the beginning.

```
from timeit import Timer
print Timer("0 in L", "L=range(100000)").timeit(number=10000)
print Timer("0 in S", "S=set(range(100000))").timeit(number=10000)
```

**Output on my machine**

```
0.00127078635541
0.00143169642464
```

**Edit:** Time complexity of different operations on various objects are documented [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Thanks @mgilson :)

Comment: @KDawG, hi, there is a similar question [How is CPython's set() implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-cpythons-set-implemented)

Comment: @KDawG Included reference in the solution. Please check now.

Comment: Ah, set doesn't allow non-hashable                                       member >>> s = set([1,[1,2,3]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>

Comment: @thefourtheye now looks complete :)

Comment: @mgilson Thanks :) Added that also in the answer :)