# Find whether an array is subset of another array hashtable way(Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I want to Find whether an array is subset of another array or not and one of the method i can think of doing it is using Hashtable but i want to implement it in python. Attached in the thread is the **c++** implementation. I'm not looking for built in functions here like set etc..

Python only has concept of dictionary in terms of hashtables but not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions would help me solve it.

Below are couple of lists:

arr1[] = [11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7]

arr2[] = [11, 3, 7, 1]

Method  (c++ Use Hashing)

1) Create a Hash Table for all the elements of arr1[].

2) Traverse arr2[] and search for each element of arr2[] in the Hash Table. If element is not found then return 0.

3) If all elements are found then return 1.

Lists can be million of numbers as well so a scalable and efficiet solution is expected.

Comment: What, are you looking for `set(arr1).issuperset(arr2)`?

Comment: No i' not looking for built in functions

Comment: sets in Python are implemented as hash tables.

Comment: @codaholic why *wouldn't* you be looking for a built-in function?

Comment: there is no as such reason but writing your own peace of code make you feel good @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez was correct. i got this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented

Comment: @codaholic I don't understand, then are you trying to write your own hash-table implementation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sought of

Comment: @codaholic well, are you looking for a scalable and efficient solution or an exercise in implementing hashing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166346/discussion-between-codaholic-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you would use `set` objects for this:

```
>>> arr1 =  [11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7]
>>> arr2 = [11, 3, 7, 1]
>>> set(arr1).issuperset(arr2)
True
```

Or more efficiently, use:

```
>>> set(arr2).issubset(arr1)
True
```

If you expect arr2 to be much smaller...

Some quick timings, it seems that they are about the same in rumtime, although, creating a `set` from `arr1` will require much more auxiliary memory:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000000,)).tolist()
>>> len(arr1)
1000000
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> arr2 = [11, 3, 7, 1]
>>> timeit('set(arr1).issuperset(arr2)', 'from __main__ import arr1, arr2', number=1000)
14.337173405918293
>>> timeit('set(arr2).issubset(arr1)', 'from __main__ import arr1, arr2', number=1000)
14.459818648989312
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `set`
e.g.
`set(arr2).issubset(arr1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i = 0
allIn = True
while i <= len(arr2) and allIn:
    if arr2[i] not in arr1:
        allIn = False
    i += 1
```

`allIn` will say whether the second list is in the first.

Note: The other solution using `set()` works equally well.

EDIT (In response to comments):

I'm not using a `for` loop as I don't know how to stop the loop from running once `allIn` is `False` (I don't know whether using `break` would work so I'm staying on the safe side).

I'm not using `set()` as the OP explicitly stated that they don't want to use in-built functions. I have posted my answer as an alternate solution to those answers already provided (but have also commended those as I believe they are better).

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but there's a couple of things wrong with this solution. First, the OP clearly cares about efficiency, and was looking for a hash-table based solution. Your current solution is actually O(N * M) because you are using a very inefficient `in` operation between lists. A hash based solution will be O(N). Finally, you should *always* use for-loops when you can over while-loops in python.

Comment: I don't this will give me an efficient solution as in case of hashtables which solves in O(1) time mostly