# In Python, what do you mean by "set is unordered"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I type `s1 = {4,3,8,1,8,2}` and check the values it always prints in ordered way as {1, 2, 3, 4, 8}. So is this is not ordered?

As per the duplicate question, even if I run there sample,

```
list1 = [8,16,24]
set(list1)        #prints {8, 16, 24}
list2 = [24,16,8]
set(list2)        #prints {8, 16, 24}
```

As per the duplicate question, they get different output. But for me as you can see every time it orders. I'm using Python 3.6.5. Is this how its suppose to behave?

Comment: @jpp this is not a duplicate of that question. For him values are coming unordered. For me its always ordered. I have seen that question. When I try this set set_1 = set([5, 2, 7, 2, 1, 88]) , I get a ordered output as {1, 2, 5, 7, 88}

Comment: See duplicate. This is know as a "coincidence".

Comment: @ jpp can you please be resonable here as for having moderator actions ? I have asked a valid question which every time I create a set in no matter what order , it always prints in order even set([5, 88, 1, 2, 7, 2,55,31,61,456,1234]) prints as {1, 2, 5, 7, 31, 55, 61, 88, 456, 1234}. I'm using python 3x here.

Comment: I'm not a moderator. Feel free to click on the "flag" link if you think this post requires moderator attention.

Comment: due to an implementation detail of CPython, the set appears ordered... but you can't rely on it being ordered... because sometimes (possibly in other implementations) it may not be.

Comment: go to http://pyfiddle.io and input `import random` and `print(set( random.sample(range(40000), k = 500)))`  - execute the script, review output. Its not ordered. qed.

Comment: It has to do with your python version, check https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation ,
`The order is preserved from python3.6`

Comment: Thank you very much . Yes I' using python 3.6.5. If you put it as an answer i can accept it :)

Comment: @Stack  according to `platform.python_version()` pyfiddle.io (if switched to 3.6) returns 3.6.1 and your News are for  **dicts** not for sets

Comment: @PatrickArtner **sets are implemented as something like dictionaries with dummy values** according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949350/8150371

Comment: @stack no idea if the space-saving changes to dicts which since then have an inbuilt ordering now effects the _pure_ set implementation - gotta read that link a bit more carefully, thanks for providing

Comment: @dnWick No problem, Can't answer as this has question has been flagged.

Comment: Oh sorry . I had to flag this. Thanks again !

Comment: A note: IPython, as a convenience, sorts `set`s when they're echoed in the REPL. You can override that behavior by explicitly calling `print()` on them, so `set`'s built-in `repr` is used, not the pretty-printed form IPython tries to use.

Comment: @Stack: That answer is wildly out-of-date at this point, thanks to *many* changes to `dict` (key-sharing `dict`s, insertion-ordered `dict`s, etc.).