# What happens when we convert from a list into a set in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, data-conversion

When we convert a list into a set, most of the time the elements in the list just shuffle up and be in a random manner. I just want to know how it happens while converting a list into a set. I here know that it excludes all the duplicates from the list and leave only one behind.

Answer (score 1):

Sets in Python don't have a defined order (they are *explicitly unordered*). Implementation-wise they are more or less the same as dictionaries and are hash-sets; converting from a list to a set would pretty much be a for-loop inserting all elements of the list to the set. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949350/4151721) for more details.

Comment: Note: The "explicitly unordered" bit (really, "arbitrarily ordered") is true of `set`s, but not `dict`s (which iterate in insertion order as an implementation detail of CPython 3.6, and a language guarantee as of 3.7), which makes your analogy to `dict`s somewhat misleading.