# Hackkerank question based on nested lists to print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade

Tags: python, list

I am new to python programming & was trying a hackkerank question based on nested lists to print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.
Link for the question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem?isFullScreen=true
Below is my code and I am getting **unhashable type:'list' error**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = int(input("Enter the length"))
    name=[]
    score=[]
    for _ in range(i):
        name.append(input())
        score.append(float(input()))
my_list=[[name,score] for _ in range(i)]
us=list(set([score for name,score in my_list]))
us.sort()
if len(us)==1:
    sl=us[0]
else:
    sl=us[1]
student=[name for name,score in my_list if score==sl]
student.sort()
print(student)
```

Please advise what is wrong with this code. I have checked all articles regarding this error but nothing fixed it.

Comment: `us=list(set([score for name,score in my_list]))` You're calling `set()` on a list-of-lists, and you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
us=list(set([score for name,score in my_list]))
```

You cannot create a set on a list containing nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the line

`us=list(set([score for name,score in my_list]))`

and I believe the same issue would arise from the line

`student=[name for name,score in my_list if score==sl]`

The output of the score list looks like a list of lists which sets cannot operate on

`[[37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]]`

If you check your my_list it looks like this

`[[['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh'], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]], [['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh'], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]], [['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh'], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]], [['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh'], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]], [['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh'], [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]]]`

You need to try and build your list to look like this

`students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]`

Not going to post the actual answer but hope this helps you understand your error

Resources:
[How is set() implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented) ,
[http://net-informations.com/python/iq/unhashable.htm#:~:text=TypeError%3A%20unhashable%20type%3A%20'list'%20usually%20means%20that%20you,it%20will%20result%20an%20error.&text=when%20you%20use%20a%20list,lists%20can't%20be%20hashed](http://net-informations.com/python/iq/unhashable.htm#:%7E:text=TypeError%3A%20unhashable%20type%3A%20%27list%27%20usually%20means%20that%20you,it%20will%20result%20an%20error.&text=when%20you%20use%20a%20list,lists%20can%27t%20be%20hashed).