# Python Time complexity of any and in and for loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity (General/Worst case) of the following lines of code?

```
s1 = "any-string-of-large-size" 
s2 = "anyother-string-of-larger-size"  
if(any(x in s1 for x in s2)):
    return "YES"
return "NO"
```

This code is for checking if there is any letter common to s1 and s2. I would also like to have any other approach to achieve this which may be more efficient.
I find it difficult to calculate time complexities when using such library functions. Can someone also please explain how to calculate it

Comment: To make this faster, you can convert one of the strings to `set` and then test `any(x in set_of_s1 for ...)` or convert both to `set` and get the set intersection. (Actually, in this very specific code, this will be slower, as this `any` return positive for the very first combination of characters, but could be O(n²) in a less-than-optimal case.)

Comment: Ohh thanks..thinking in your lines, I think it can be made more faster by using this: `return "YES" if set(s1) & set(s2) else "NO"`. What would be the time complexity in this case ?

Comment: Exactly. Time complexity would then be O(n) for creating the two sets and the intersection. Using `any` with `in a_set` might be faster (still O(n) though), as this will only have to create one set and then stop early as soon as the first match is found.

Comment: So is the time complexity for  intersection `&`  O(n) or O(1) ?

Comment: Time complexity for intersection is O(n), since you have to make a O(1) lookup for all the n elements in the set.

Comment: Oh Okay...Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and worst case are `O(1)` and `O(|s1|*|s2|)`, respectively, where `|s1|` and `|s2|` denote the length of the two strings.

Indeed, your code could be rewritten as

```
for c2 in s2:
   for c1 in s1:
      if c1==c2:
          return "YES"
return "NO"
```

If you just want to check if the two string share a common char you could write it as

```
if set(s1) & set(s2):
   return "YES"
return "NO"
```

This would have the same worst case time complexity `O(|s1|*|s2|)`, but the average case would be `O(min(|s1|,|s2|)`.

Comment: It's the worst case considering collisions, unluckily to happen, but still https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Of course, the worst case in the double-loop-scenario is _much_ more likely.

Comment: @abc Could you please explain what you mean by collisions?

Comment: @Dev5 I think this thread cover your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(N) in general for (in) keyword. So x in s2 is straight forward O(N). Which concludes overall complexity to be O(N^2).