# Removing indexes from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm facing a somewhat troubling problem: I have a list (for example `(2, 5, 7, 3, 8)`) and I need to remove a couple of those but not all. Let's say I need to remove indexes `1`, `3` and `4` and I want to do that in a loop. Is there anyway (in Python or logically) to remove those indexes easily in a loop.

If I have a list `remIndexes = (1, 3, 4)`, as soon as I remove index `1`, everything moves down one, so now I have `(2, 7, 3, 8)` and the indexes for the numbers I wanted to remove are shifted down by one.

Does python provide a neat way of doing this or am I going to have to order the list `remIndexes` and then go backwards through the list?

Note: remIndexes should be in order, but it could potentially not be in order. Ordering it isn't very hard, however.

UPDATE:

Why does

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
for ind, num in enumerate(lst):
    print lst.pop(ind)
```

actually work????? (It prints `2 4 6 8 0` each on a newline.)

Does python freeze a list while you are in a for loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting multiple elements from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the reversed indexes:

```
>>> lst = [2, 5, 7, 3, 8]
>>> indexes = 1, 3, 4
>>> for i in reversed(indexes):
...     del lst[i]
...
>>> lst
[2, 7]
```

Or use `sorted(indexes, reverse=True)` if the indexes is not sorted.

---

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> lst = [2, 5, 7, 3, 8]
>>> indexes = 1, 3, 4
>>> indexes = set(indexes)  # `x in set` is faster than `x in tuple/list`
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in indexes]
[2, 7]
```

Comment: I didn't know about reversed. However, you also forgot to order indexes

Comment: Also, this was what I was afraid I would have to do; is there anything else that is neater?

Comment: Smartest answer to this problem provided by @falsetru.
You basically sort your indexes by descending order, so you won't have to worry about the list getting adjusted after each deletion.

Comment: Interestingl I didn't think of that... the enumerate .. if not in indexes.

Comment: Umm... question: why does `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]\ for ind, num in enumerate(a): print a.pop(ind)` work? I thought it would, but it actually does. Does python make the list `a` temporarily "locked" such that removing an index while in a for loop doesn't shift them all down?

Comment: @Miche (a)Someone... new part of the question... see update or above comment. Why?

Comment: list.pop(index) removes the element but doesn't affect the keys, hence in your example, it does work, but it could give you some weird behavior in another context since you don't really see if you are still within the bounds of your list.