# How can I delete items from my list of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use a list of indices to remove items from my list of tuples:

```
mytupList = [(1,2),(2,3),(5,6),(8,9)]
indxList = [1,3]
```

I have tried using numpy like so:

```
newtupList = numpy.delete(mytupList,indxList).tolist()
```

but it has not worked.

I want my newtupList = [(1,2),(5,6)]

what am I doing wrong? I have also tried:

```
a = np.array(mytupList) 
newtup = np.delete((a),indxList)
```

but this does not produce the desired result.

Comment: How it "has not worked"? What result was produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [`docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), you need to use the `axis` option there, because without it being mentioned it would delete elements on a flattened version. Thus, you need to do like this -

```
np.delete(mytupList,indxList,axis=0).tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [21]: mytupList
Out[21]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 6), (8, 9)]

In [22]: indxList
Out[22]: [1, 3]

In [23]: np.delete(mytupList,indxList).tolist() # Flattens and deletes
Out[23]: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]

In [24]: np.delete(mytupList,indxList,axis=0).tolist() # Correct usage
Out[24]: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

---

To retain the format of list of tuples, use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) after deleting, like so -

```
map(tuple,np.delete(mytupList,indxList,axis=0))
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: map(tuple,np.delete(mytupList,indxList,axis=0))
Out[16]: [(1, 2), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: This produces a list of lists [[1,2],[5,6]]  - Is there any way to retain the list of tuples?

Comment: @wunderkind Check out the edits at the end please.

Comment: Excellent! that works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

My answer in this post: [Deleting multiple elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list/28697246#28697246)

```
for i in sorted(indices, reverse=True):
    del somelist[i]
```

See that this does remove the items you want instead of making a new list a replace the original variable with the new list. (I haven't tested which on is more efficient, I would expect this one if the list is large enough)

Comment: mylist = [(23,23),(434,353),(353,3535),(1425,475)]

Comment: oops...yes that does work as well (tested) although I was convinced that I could this on a list of tuples. More efficient as in faster?

Comment: I did not get your question. Do this on a list of tuples? Didn't work? And yes, efficient as 'more faster'.

Comment: ok so I generated a list of tuples which are coordinate points and found some code to create polylines from pair of the pairs of tuples. I have to do more reading about lists, tuples and list comprehensions as it seems I did not understand that a list containing tuples can be treated as a normal list. So I became fixated on find a solution to deal with tuples and used the solution suggested by @Divakar and discounted yours. However yours does work thanks.

Comment: UPDATE - @tglaria I've tested your solution on a small list of tuples and it works but when I try it on a larger dataset (1000s of tuples) I get what had feared would happen:                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\mytests\coords.py", line 71, in <module>
    del pairt[i]
TypeError: 'tuple' object doesn't support item deletion.                                                                                                        Divakar's solution doesn't produce this tuple issue

Comment: @wunderkind this would happen when you're trying to delete an item from a tuple. Are you sure your data is EXACTLY a list of tuples? This solution lets you delete any item from a LIST, no matter its contents. It doesn't matter if it's a list of tuples, strings or whatever. Could you paste your data somewhere to check your problem?