# How to remove multiple items from a list in just one statement?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

In python, I know how to remove items from a list:

```
item_list = ['item', 5, 'foo', 3.14, True]
item_list.remove('item')
item_list.remove(5)
```

The above code removes the values 5 and 'item' from `item_list`.
But when there is a lot of stuff to remove, I have to write many lines of:

```
item_list.remove("something_to_remove")
```

If I know the index of what I am removing, I use:

```
del item_list[x]
```

where x is the index of the item I want to remove.

If I know the index of all of the numbers that I want to remove, I'll use some sort of loop to `del` the items at the indices.

But what if I don't know the indices of the items I want to remove?

I tried `item_list.remove('item', 'foo')`, but I got an error saying that `remove` only takes one argument.

Is there a way to remove multiple items from a list in a single statement?

P.S. I've used `del` and `remove`. Can someone explain the difference between these two, or are they the same?

Comment: To answer your second question: `del` deletes an item by its index. The `remove` function of a list finds an item's index and then calls `del` on that index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting multiple elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list)

Comment: Can your list contain duplicates? `l.remove(value)` only removes the first occurrence of value. Consider the list ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a']. If you want to remove all occurrences of a value, it's less grief to use a list comprehension than iteratively doing `del` or `.remove()`.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

In Python, creating a new object e.g. with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is often better than modifying an existing one:

```
item_list = ['item', 5, 'foo', 3.14, True]
item_list = [e for e in item_list if e not in ('item', 5)]
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
item_list = ['item', 5, 'foo', 3.14, True]
new_list = []
for e in item_list:
    if e not in ('item', 5):
        new_list.append(e)
item_list = new_list
```

In case of a big list of filtered out values (here, `('item', 5)` is a small set of elements), using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is faster as the `in` operation [is O(1) time complexity on average](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). It's also a good idea to build the iterable you're removing first, so that you're not creating it on every iteration of the list comprehension:

```
unwanted = {'item', 5}
item_list = [e for e in item_list if e not in unwanted]
```

A [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is also a good solution if memory is not cheap.

Comment: Is the set optimised in python 2 or is it only optimised in python 3? By that I mean is the set created only once when the bytecode is generated?

Comment: Set is, [by definition](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), optimized for `in` operation. See [this benchmarks](https://github.com/Aluriak/__contains__-comparison) for comparisons of the four primitive data structures. Yes, the set is built at each loop, as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/Aluriak/01c3d100cb44ef048c00854c6f439642), consequently save the set in a dedicated variable to use in the generator expression can save time.

Comment: I came across this question. I just want to point out that the original list may contain duplicates and the intention to remove element may simply be remove as many element as in the remove-list. The above method will ended up eliminating all duplicates. Not necessary the right behavior.

Comment: @aluriak benchmarks as of python 3.9.7 seem to give different results. if you have a complex iterable you're filtering by, then pre-building the iterable is best, but set vs. list gives about the same result. for simple iterables (simple membership of small iterables), then set does outperform lists. see [this adaptation of your experiment](https://gist.github.com/chucklesoclock/5269aa5e42b6cc51ae8aece07f1381a0).

Comment: When you introduce an important new concept like a list comprehension that OP has almost surely never seen before and doesn't exist in most languages, name it (and hyperlink it). Don't just show them the code.

Answer (score 51):

You can do it in one line by converting your lists to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s and using [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
item_list = ['item', 5, 'foo', 3.14, True]
list_to_remove = ['item', 5, 'foo']

final_list = list(set(item_list) - set(list_to_remove))
```

Would give you the following output:

```
final_list = [3.14, True]
```

**Note**: this will remove duplicates in your input list and the elements in the output can be in any order (because `set`s don't preserve order). It also requires all elements in both of your lists to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable).

Comment: nope, it shuffles the items in the list. Use only if the order of items do not matter, which it does quite often.

Comment: This will also remove duplicates from the list. Not that it matters for the example list though

Comment: It will remove duplicates! The answer can cause serious bugs, please do not use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reposting my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056160/python-list-remove-multiple-items/48056321#48056321) because I saw it also fits in here.
It allows removing multiple values or removing only duplicates of these values 
and returns either a new list or modifies the given list in place.

---

```
def removed(items, original_list, only_duplicates=False, inplace=False):
    """By default removes given items from original_list and returns
    a new list. Optionally only removes duplicates of `items` or modifies
    given list in place.
    """
    if not hasattr(items, '__iter__') or isinstance(items, str):
        items = [items]

    if only_duplicates:
        result = []
        for item in original_list:
            if item not in items or item not in result:
                result.append(item)
    else:
        result = [item for item in original_list if item not in items]

    if inplace:
        original_list[:] = result
    else:
        return result
```

Docstring extension:

```
"""
Examples:
---------

    >>>li1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    >>>removed(4, li1)
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
    >>>removed((4,5), li1)
       [1, 2, 3]
    >>>removed((4,5), li1, only_duplicates=True)
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # remove all duplicates by passing original_list also to `items`.:
    >>>removed(li1, li1, only_duplicates=True)
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # inplace:
    >>>removed((4,5), li1, only_duplicates=True, inplace=True)
    >>>li1
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    >>>li2 =['abc', 'def', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi']
    >>>removed(('def', 'ghi'), li2, only_duplicates=True, inplace=True)
    >>>li2
        ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
"""
```

---

You should be clear about what you really want to do, modify an existing list, or make a new list with
the specific items missing. It's important to make that distinction in case you have a second reference pointing
to the existing list. If you have, for example...

```
li1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
li2 = li1
# then rebind li1 to the new list without the value 4
li1 = removed(4, li1)
# you end up with two separate lists where li2 is still pointing to the 
# original
li2
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
li1
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

This may or may not be the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) function from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) module

Example

```
import random
from itertools import filterfalse

random.seed(42)

data = [random.randrange(5) for _ in range(10)]
clean = [*filterfalse(lambda i: i == 0, data)]
print(f"Remove 0s\n{data=}\n{clean=}\n")


clean = [*filterfalse(lambda i: i in (0, 1), data)]
print(f"Remove 0s and 1s\n{data=}\n{clean=}")
```

Output:

```
Remove 0s
data=[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4]
clean=[2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]

Remove 0s and 1s
data=[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4]
clean=[2, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this -

Suppose we have a list, `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`

We want to delete last two items in a single statement

```
del l[3:]
```

We have output:

> l = [1,2,3]

Keep it Simple

Answer (score 1):

we can remove multiple elements

list1=[1,2,3,4,5,200,30]

del list1[1:3]

print(list1)

[1,4,5,200,30]

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I don't know the indices of the items I want to remove?

I do not exactly understand why you do not like .remove but to get the first index corresponding to a value use .index(value):

```
ind=item_list.index('item')
```

then remove the corresponding value:

```
del item_list[ind]
```

.index(value) gets the first occurrence of value, and .remove(value) removes the first occurrence of value. You are welcome.

Comment: Consider using `del item_list[ind]` instead of `pop` if you don't need the result value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everyone forgot to mention the amazing capability of `set`s in python. You can simply cast your list into a set and then remove whatever you want to remove in a simple expression like so:

```
>>> item_list = ['item', 5, 'foo', 3.14, True]
>>> item_list = set(item_list) - {'item', 5}
>>> item_list
{True, 3.14, 'foo'}
>>> # you can cast it again in a list-from like so
>>> item_list = list(item_list)
>>> item_list
[True, 3.14, 'foo']
```

Comment: Does not maintain the order of the objects though.

Comment: And also will remove duplicates that potentially exist in the list.

Comment: "why everyone forgot to mention [...] `set`s". Because they didn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/42243963/3064538

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have **my_list**  as below. We would like to remove the duplicated 0's from our list. By using remove(), only one 0 can be removed, whereas the next code can remove all the duplicated 0's at once:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4]
list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, my_list))

output:

[1, 3, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the numpy array and set function to end up with a new array that only shows the elements you want to keep.

```
import numpy as np
# given an array A:
A = [5,78,423,87,45,78,4]
# first convert your array to a numpy array
A_np = np.array(A)
# specify the indices you want to remove
inds_to_be_deleted = [3,5]
# find the remaining indices using set function
remaining_inds = list(set(range(len(A)))-set(inds_to_be_deleted))
# the new array will only contain the elements at the remaining indices
A_new = A_np[remaining_inds]
```

which gives you this output:
array([  5,  78, 423,  45,   4])