# Python List remove multiple items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to remove multiple occurrences of a value from a list.The output does not remove any of the desired items.

```
def rem(a,li):
try:
    while a in li == True:
        li.remove(a)
    print('Updated list: ',li)
except ValueError:
    print(a,' is not located in the list ',li)
```

Example to trying out function:

```
L = [1,2,3,45,3,2,3,3,4,5]
```

rem(2,L)

Output: Updated list:  [1, 2, 3, 45, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Is it intended to remove the value entirely? Or do you just want to reduce it one instance.

Comment: what's your expected output? Are you trying to remove ALL occurrences of `a` or just the repeated ones? e.g.  if `lst = [1,2,3,4,5,5]` and you call `rem(5,lst)`, are you expecting the output `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `[1,2,3,4]`?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 mistakes in your code. The first one is

`while a in li == True:` In fact, this check always returns **False** since `li == True` is **False**.

It should actually be `while (a in li) == True:`, or `while a in li:`

Also, if you are trying to delete only **repeated** occurrences of `a` (i.e. leave the first occurrence of `a` in) then list comprehension won't suit your needs. You will have to add an additional check inside your `rem()` function that catches the first occurrence of `a` and *then* executes your loop:

```
def rem(a, li):
  list_length = len(li)
  i = 0
  while (li[i] != a) and (i < list_length):
    i += 1              # skip to the first occurrence of a in li
  i += 1                # increment i 
  while i < list_length:
    if li[i] == a:
      del li[i]
      print('Updated list: ', li)
      list_length -= 1          # decrement list length after removing occurrence of a
    else:
      i += 1
```

The code snippet above does not cover the edge cases where the list is empty, or the case `a` is not in the list. I'll leave those exercises to you.

Comment: This is pretty complicated for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the while condition to `while a in li`

```
def rem(a,li):
    try:
        while a in li:
            li.remove(a)
        print('Updated list: ',li)
    except ValueError:
        print(a,' is not located in the list ',li)

L = [1,2,3,45,3,2,3,3,4,5]
rem(2,L)
```

In general, if you want to remove duplicates from a list then you can use the built-in `set`.

Comment: Thanks that works. does python interpret a in li as already containing the comparison of being equal to True? That is the only logic I can deduce from the code.

Comment: @evan yes, you're right! there're better ways to do this as you can see from other answers.

Comment: What's the point of the try...except... ? You already have `while a in li`, therefore `a` has to be in `li` when `li.remove(a)` is called. When will a `ValueError` ever occur? (To be an acceptable answer, unnecessary code should be removed)

Comment: @abccd thanks for the feedback; this concept being quite new to me, will follow going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove all instances of `a` from `L`, you could also just use a simple list comprehension:

```
def rem(a,li):
    return [x for x in li if x != a]

L = [1,2,3,45,3,2,3,3,4,5]
print(rem(2,L))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 45, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be a better job for a list comprehension.
`L[:] = [a for a in L if a not in (2,)]`
Assigning to a slice will mutate the list in place.

---

---

I'm updating my answer to account for the various interpretations your question allows
and also to make it more general by accepting **also strings** and **multiple values** to be removed at once.

```
def removed(items, original_list, only_duplicates=False, inplace=False):
    """By default removes given items from original_list and returns
    a new list. Optionally only removes duplicates of `items` or modifies
    given list in place.
    """
    if not hasattr(items, '__iter__') or isinstance(items, str):
        items = [items]

    if only_duplicates:
        result = []
        for item in original_list:
            if item not in items or item not in result:
                result.append(item)
    else:
        result = [item for item in original_list if item not in items]

    if inplace:
        original_list[:] = result
    else:
        return result
```

Docstring extension:

```
"""
Examples:
---------

    >>>li1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    >>>removed(4, li1)
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
    >>>removed((4,5), li1)
       [1, 2, 3]
    >>>removed((4,5), li1, only_duplicates=True)
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # remove all duplicates by passing original_list also to `items`.:
    >>>removed(li1, li1, only_duplicates=True)
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # inplace:
    >>>removed((4,5), li1, only_duplicates=True, inplace=True)
    >>>li1
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    >>>li2 =['abc', 'def', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi']
    >>>removed(('def', 'ghi'), li2, only_duplicates=True, inplace=True)
    >>>li2
        ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
"""
```

---

You should be clear about what you really want to do, modify an existing list, or make a new list with
the specific items missing. It's important to make that distinction in case you have a second reference pointing
to the existing list. If you have, for example...

```
li1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
li2 = li1
# then rebind li1 to the new list without the value 4
li1 = removed(4, li1)
# you end up with two separate lists where li2 is still pointing to the 
# original
li2
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
li1
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

This may or may not be the behaviour you want.

Comment: It's not necessary if you don't care if a new list is created, but how the question is phrased I understand he want's to mutate the list, not replace it. You can check with `id(L)` that the list is still the same as before when you assign to a slice, while it gets a new id in case you skip the slice.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of index no and use `del`

Simple approach:

```
L = [1,2,3,45,3,2,3,3,4,5]

def rem(a,li):
    for j,i in enumerate(li):
        if a==i:
            del li[j]

    return li



print(rem(2,L))
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 45, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```