# Delete multiple elements in a list by index in Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to delete multiple items in a list by their index:

```
dS = [0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0]
dN = [1, 0.02, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9]
pos = [i for i, e in enumerate(dS) if e ==0]
```

And now I would like to delete (in both lists) all the items on the positions of 0's in the first list.

Comment: which language?

Comment: Python, I edited the title

Comment: Could you add some data? Input-output?

Comment: See previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268749/remove-multiple-items-from-a-python-list-in-just-one-statement

Comment: I'd change your list comprehension for a generator, instead of a list, for performance `pos = (i for i, e in enumerate(dS) if e ==0)` and after, run through the list and delete each one: `for idx in pos[::-1]: del dS[idx]`
You see I reversed the list in order to don't change the numbers that will be deleted

Comment: something like `[dN[i] for i, e in enumerate(dS) if e]`

Comment: @LuanNaufal I doubt a generator will improve performance, I suspect it will actually make it *worse*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, with timeit, both options indeed have different performances, and with generator, it works faster (even though the difference is not huge):
0.12277622299734503 (with list)
0.11267214198596776 (with generator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have any `old_list` with a list of index `pos` that you want to get rid of:

```
new_list = [old_list[i] for i, e in enumerate(old_list) if i not in pos]
```

This will work for both the list in your question by getting rid of the element at index specified by `pos`, just substitute `old_list` with list name you currently have:

```
dS = [0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0]
dN = [1, 0.02, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9]
pos = [i for i, e in enumerate(dS) if e ==0]
dS = [dS[i] for i, e in enumerate(dS) if i not in pos]
dN = [dN[i] for i, e in enumerate(dN) if i not in pos]
>>> dS, dN
([0.02, 0.04, 0.07], [0.02, 0.7, 0.9])
```

This work fine for list which lengths are different, as shown in your case above.

Comment: This feels the most Pythonic to me. It's readable, and each list of `dS` and `dN` are independent of each other.

Comment: `pos` should probably be a `set` for faster lookup

Comment: You could also use directly the "e" variable and get rid of the lookup, as in `dS = [e for i, e in enumerate(dS) if i not in pos]`

Comment: @RockyLi, comparing your solution with the one I suggested (this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53564806/10642035), yours, since you're creating 2 new lists for the task, is way slower (2 times as slow). 
Using timeit to compare both, here the measurement, using 100000 runs:
Mine - 0.15612420099205337
Yours - 0.3033675350015983

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to delete (in both lists) all the items on the positions of 0's in the first list.

Okay first process the second list by picking only the items of the same index than the non-zero items of the first list:

```
dN = [dN[i] for i, e in enumerate(dS) if e]
```

then do the same for `dS` (note: a variant would be to use `filter` in that case):

```
dS = list(filter(None,dS))
```

Comment: This assumes both lists are of the same length. If `dN` is larger, this solution will truncate its elements in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of making new copies of each list with certain elements omitted, or modifying both lists in place.

```
dS = [0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0]
dN = [1, 0.02, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9]

# make copies of both lists while omitting indices
# that corresponds to zeros in dS
dS, dN = map(list, zip(*[(s, n) for s, n in zip(dS, dN) if s != 0]))

# alternatively, modify lists inplace
dS = [0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0]
dN = [1, 0.02, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9]

# process lists in reverse
for i in range(1, len(dS)):
    try:
        if dS[-i] == 0:
            del dS[-i], dN[-i]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists have different lengths, you only need to run through your list pos and delete from both lists, such as: (important to run in reverse order in the pos, to ensure you won't try to delete an element index that no longer exists)

```
for idx in pos[::-1]:
        del dS[idx]
        if idx < len(dN):
            del dN[idx]
```