# How to remove elements from a list in a certain pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have been trying to work on this certain pattern for quite some time but I am unable to come up with a solution. For example I have list like: `n = ['M', 'M', 'B', 'B']`.

Now, I know how to remove the elements from a list that have odd indexes or even indexes like `del n[1::2]` for odd indexes and `del n[0::2]` for even indexes.

However, I am looking to remove in a pattern like this: `0, [1], 2, [3], [5], [8].....` so on and so forth. The brackets are for the elements in those certain indexes to be removed.

The `n` list is just an example, I have much larger lists with more elements. So far, all the things I have tried haven't worked and I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: What's the pattern behind `0, 1, [1], 2, [3], [5], [8]`? Obviously you are talking about the fibonacci sequence, but what classifies an element as an "index to be removed"?

Comment: Please specify what's the pattern you want to delete the elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting multiple elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list)

Comment: Presumably `0, 1, [1], 2 ...` is a typo and should read `0, [1], 2 ...`

Comment: @jarmod thanks, I will be editing it

Comment: @jarmod: I doubt that. 0,1,1,2,3,5,8 is the fibonacci sequence. But the indices to remove seem to have no particular order. There is no algorithm that follows "whatever assumption", so we need to know this information ... Edit: question has been edited. Now the list makes even less sense. Please enlighten us, Mahir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
orig_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
indices_to_retain = [0, 1, 4]

new_list = [content for entry, content in enumerate(orig_list) if entry in indices_to_retain]
# [1, 2, 5]
```