# How to remove element from a list using other list?

Tags: python, list

I have two list
`a =[72,82,955,55,.....]`
and
`b=[5,7,8...]`
I want to remove the element from a. list b specifies the indexes from where elements to be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting multiple elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *list comprehension* in combination with `enumerate` method in order to apply condition based on the `index`.

```
result = [item for index, item in enumerate(a) if index not in b]
```