# How to simultaneously delete multiple values from a list in Python based on their index?

Tags: python, list, element

How to delete all the elements from a list that have their corresponding index in another list?

```
a = [1,13,15,16,22,70,3]
index_list = [3,6]
```

So the final list should look like this:

```
a = [1,13,15,22,70] # because we removed the elements that have their index equal to 3 and 6.
```

I tried this, but as the length of the list is modified because of the deletion, it destroys the proper removing:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a):
     del a[index_list[i]]
     i +=1
     if (i < len(a)-1):
        index_list[i+1] = index_list[i+1] - 1
```

And I got an error.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
a = [e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i not in index_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [i for j, i in enumerate(a) if j not in index_list]
```

from: [Deleting multiple elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497426/deleting-multiple-elements-from-a-list), or less pythonic:

```
result = []
for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if j not in index_list:
        result.add(i)
```

Comment: note: if `index_list` is longer than couple dozen of indexes, it's better to convert it to a set first.

Answer (score 1):

If returning a new object with the same data is ok, use a list comprehension:

```py
a = [val for j, val in enumerate(a) if j not in index_list]
```

Sometimes however, you may want to modify the original object in-place. In that case you could do something like this:

```py
# get index list in reverse order
drop_inds = sorted(index_list, reverse=True)

# drop elements in-place
for idx in drop_inds:
    del a[idx]
```

Comment: It's also faster, btw. Imagine for example the extreme case where we want to delete *all* elements. Deleting front to back would take quadratic time, while deleting back to front would take linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming index_list contents are valid for `a`s actual size, you won't have a problem if you delete from the end of the list to the start:

```
a = [1,13,15,16,22,70,3]
index_list = [3,6]
for pos in reversed(index_list):
    a.pop(pos)
print(f"{a=}")
```

To make it into a more capable one-line which strips out duplicates in the removal list and returns what was removed:

```
a = [1,13,15,16,22,70,3]
index_list = [3,6,6]

print(f"before:{a=}")
removed = [a.pop(pos) for pos in reversed(list(set(index_list)))]

print(f"{removed=}")
print(f"after :{a=}")
```

output:

```
before:a=[1, 13, 15, 16, 22, 70, 3]
removed=[3, 16]
after :a=[1, 13, 15, 22, 70]
```

output:

`a=[1, 13, 15, 22, 70]`

You could even add a bit of filtering to take out indices in the removal list that are not in the bounds of `a`s length.